# SQL Database in Android doesnt work

Tags: java, android, sql, database, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create a database with 3 columns name, wins, losses.
The datatable should have only one line - only one player.
I tried to do that but it is not working, the app always crashes.
I have 2 activities and one regular class. In the main activity it checks if the players name is in the database and if not it asks him to enter his name.
in the second activity (GameActivity) it supposes to show me his name and how much time he won and lost to the computer. There are 2 buttons in there, add win and add loss, each one should raise the number of the wins or losses. 
The sql database class extend SQLiteOpenHelper

MainActivity

```
SQLGameTable db;
Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.leaderboards);
    db = new SQLGameTable(this);
    if(db.getName() == "")
    {
        final Score score = new Score("", 0, 0);
        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        send.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
        et.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String name = et.getText().toString();
                score.setName(name);
            }
        });
        db.addPlayer("Daniel", score.getWins(), score.getLoses());
        send.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
        et.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    final Intent i = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

GameActivity

```
Button aWin, aLose;
SQLGameTable scoreTable;
TextView tv1, tv3, tv4;
Score score;
String name;
int win=0, lose=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    scoreTable = new SQLGameTable(this);
    aWin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    aLose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    name = scoreTable.getName();
    win = scoreTable.getWin();
    lose = scoreTable.getLose();
    tv1.setText(name + "");
    tv3.setText(win + "");
    tv4.setText(lose + "");
    aLose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            lose++;
            scoreTable.reset();
            scoreTable.addPlayer(name, win, lose);
            lose = scoreTable.getLose();
            tv4.setText("" + (lose));
        }
    });
    aWin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            win++;
            scoreTable.reset();
            scoreTable.addPlayer(name, win, lose);
            win = scoreTable.getWin();
            tv3.setText("" + (win));
        }
    });
}
```

SQLGameTable extends SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public static String DATABASE_NAME = "highscores";
public static String TABLE_NAME = "scores";
public static String KEY_ID = "id";
public static String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static String KEY_WIN = "win";
public static String KEY_LOSE = "lose";
public SQLGameTable(Context c) 
{
    super(c, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name STRING, win INTEGER, lose INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{

}

public void addPlayer(String name, int win, int lose) 
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    values.put(KEY_WIN, win);
    values.put(KEY_LOSE, lose);
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
public void reset() 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    db.close();
}
public String getName() 
{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    int row = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    db.close();
    return c.getString(row);
}
public int getWin() 
{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    int row = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WIN);
    db.close();
    return Integer.parseInt(c.getString(row));
}
public int getLose() 
{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    int row = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOSE);
    db.close();
    return Integer.parseInt(c.getString(row));
}
```

Comment: Define `doesnt work`. What does your logcat say?

Comment: can you give us a stack trace?

Comment: It crashes after I click on the button to start the other activity it say "Unfortunatly, APP_NAME has stopped."

Comment: What is a stack trace and how can I do it?

Comment: `You don't do it, it happens` naturally. It's what the logcat reports. I hope you have set a logcat view in your IDE configuration...

Comment: @DerGolem  no... I dont know what it is..

Comment: **Your bad**. You must `study a little bit`, before starting programming.

Comment: @DerGolem I study it in the high school and the teacher didnt say a word about it so actually its not my bad.. but can you tell me what to study and from where?

Comment: You `shouldn't depend on your teacher`'s teaching method. And it's not **his/her** fault, if **you** don't deepen your knowledge. As a "scientist" (`I like to call me so`) - or a wo/man of knowledge, you should always **research**.  **At least**, study your IDE documentation. **Debugging** is of vital importance, in programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your Android app's `SQL` `database` is related to implementation of `SQLGameTable` class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

You don't call `db.getName()` to verify the player's name in `database`. It seem like you may try to retrieve the name of a player from `database`. It's not clear what `SQL` do in this method.

Another issue is in your `GameActivity`. You call `scoreTable.getWin()` and `scoreTable.getLose()` to bring the number of wins and losses.

Debug this issue adding some `log` statements to the code to see where it crashes and what vals are being retrieved from `database`. You can add a log statement calling `db.getName()` in `MainActivity` to see the val.

---

Check if `database` is created:

`onCreate` in `SQLGameTable` is responsible for creating `database` and `score tables`. You add a log to chekc if they're being called and if the table is beign created.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name STRING, win INTEGER, lose INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    Log.d("SQLGameTable", "Database created successfully"); // Add this log statement
}
```

---

Check if `database` is opened:

`getWritableDatabase` in the `SQLGameTable` is responsable for opening `database`. You add a log to check if it is called.

```
public void addPlayer(String name, int win, int lose) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    values.put(KEY_WIN, win);
    values.put(KEY_LOSE, lose);
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
    Log.d("SQLGameTable", "Player added successfully"); // Add this log statement
}
```

---

Check if `column` name is correct:

Column names in `SQLGameTable` has to match column names in the scores.

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "scores";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_WIN = "win";
public static final String KEY_LOSE = "lose";
```

---

Check if `table` name is correct:

Table name in `SQLGameTable` has to match table name in the scores.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name STRING, win INTEGER, lose INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    Log.d("SQLGameTable", "Database created successfully");
}

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "scores";
```

`onCreate` creates a `table`, and `TABLE_NAME` in `SQLGameTable` is set to "scores".

---

Check if you added the necessary permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` file to access `SQLite` `database`.